# I get the error: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Tags: java, matrix, inner-classes

I'm new to java, but I faced so many problems with this recent assignment (creating matrices using 6 different ways). Anyway, I cannot seem to figure out how to go about this problem: 
We are suposed to implement a 3x3 matrix using a record of 3 rows; and each row should be a record of 3 columns. Where the input is an array of 9 elements representing the matrix row wise.
I keep getting the error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"
for the mat = new Row3(long [] array); part of the code

```
public class Matrix3x3rc 
{

    private Row3 mat;

    private class column3
    {
        final long var1;
        final long var2;
        final long var3;

        private column3(long value1, long value2, long value3)
        {
            this.var1 = value1;
            this.var2 = value2;
            this.var3 = value3;
        }
    }

    private class Row3
    {
        final column3 row1;
        final column3 row2;
        final column3 row3;

        private Row3(long [] array)
        {
            this.row1 = new column3(array[0],array[1],array[2]);
            this.row2 = new column3(array[3],array[4],array[5]);
            this.row3 = new column3(array[6],array[7],array[9]);
        }
    }

    public Matrix3x3rc(long [] array ){
        mat = new Row3(long [] array);
```

Comment: Also, I want to know how can I assign, a value to mat this doesn't work so? long [][] original = mat; –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mat = new Row3(long [] array);
```

should be

```
mat = new Row3(array);
```

When you are calling a method (or constructor) you don't have to specify the type of the argument you are passing.

Comment: Also, I want to know how can I assign, a value to mat
this doesn't work so?
long [][] original = mat;

Comment: @MOSTAFAOKASHA I don't see where you have a statement such as `long [][] original = mat;`, but it can't work, since `mat` is of type Row3, which is not an array. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to make another variable equal to mat so that I can store the values in it in the same format...I thought mat was type array?
Is there a way to do this by changing the code a bit?